# finding average with list.fold

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Just trying to make a really simple average `float list -> float`, that finds the average of a list.
This is my code:

```
let list ls = List.fold (fun acc float -> acc + float) 0.0 ls;;

list [1.60; 2.30; 5.0; 2.30];;
```

The output is `11.2`

I need something added to the function that can divide `11.2` with `x` elements to find the average.

Any help?

Comment: I assume that you want to do this with `fold` as an excercise in FP. Otherwise, there's the `List.average` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to iterate the list only once you can just count up it's length in parallel (using a tuple `(sum, len)´ as an accumulator) and then divide afterwards:

```
let avg xs = 
   xs 
   |> List.fold (fun (sum,len) x -> (sum+x,len+1.0)) (0.0,0.0) 
   |> (fun (sum,len) -> sum / len)
```

which can be written in a point-free style if you like:

```
let avg = 
   List.fold (fun (sum,len) x -> (sum+x,len+1.0)) (0.0,0.0) 
   >> (fun (sum,len) -> sum / len)
```

this gives you:

```
> avg [1.0;2.0;3.0];;
val it : float = 2.0
```

---

but of course the easiest way to extent your function is to just get the length of the list and divide by it:

```
let avg ls = 
   List.fold (fun acc float -> acc + float) 0.0 ls / (float ls.Length)
```

for the list this will not make any difference - but you can extend the above version to seqs easily and there it **will** make a difference (iterate the seq once or twice):

```
let avg : float seq -> float = 
   Seq.fold (fun (sum,len) x -> (sum+x,len+1.0)) (0.0,0.0) 
   >> (fun (sum,len) -> sum / len)
```

Comment: In the example with dividing by length of the list you could use `(+)` as first argument to `fold` instead of the lambda.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin yes that's true ... I shamelessly copied the OPs function (although I did rename it) - I think maybe it's easier to spot what the important part is this way - but thank you for the hint

Comment: The easiest would've been just `List.average` which is the predefined library function dividing the sum of by the number of elements. Note that it uses an integer as divisor; a home-brewed equivalent would be something like `let inline avg list = let sum,len=((LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero,0), list)||> List.fold (fun (sum,len) x -> (sum+x,len+1)) in LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt sum len`